# Why doesn't my script create new elements in a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to make a 2048 game copy for a project, I've created everything nice and well but when I get to the testing the function that creates the board doesn't add any divs inside the desired container or anywhere. This is the part that should create that :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoader',() => {
const table = document.querySelector(".grid");
const scoreboard = document.getElementById("score");
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById("result");
const width = 4;

function gameBoard(){
    let squares = [];
    for(let i=0; i < width*width; i++){
        square = document.createElement("div");
        square.innerHTML = 0;
        table.appendChild(square);    
        squares.push(square);
    }
}
gameBoard();
```

The html element that I want to fill is another div with class="grid"( i messed up with this in the original , i meant to say class not id, sorry for the confsion).
Any help would be much appreciated.

Also here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>.:>2048<:.</title>
<meta charset="utf8">
<link   rel="stylesheet" href="estilos/estilo.css">
<script src="scripts/probas.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="score-container">
     <div class="score-annouce">Puntuación</div>
    <span id="score">0</span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: another typo: `DOMContentLoaded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMContentLoader` to `DOMContentLoaded`, like what Temani said, and close your code with `});`, then it'll fix the error and run the loop.